# Using external JS file to make changes on a Servlet's HTML output

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

I want to do a simple thing.

I have a servlet. Inside the `DoPost()` function I'm writing HTML output to be shown in the browser. This HTML includes a single image. When clicking this image I want to alert its element id.

servlet:

```
public void printSinglePlayerBoard(int i_PlayerNumber, HttpServletResponse respose)
throws IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>\n");
    out.println("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'
    src='functions.js'></script>\n");
    out.println("<body>\n");
    out.print("<img id='someID' src='somePath' onclick='func(someID)'/>");
    out.print("</form>\n</body>\n</html>\n");
}
```

functions.js:

```
function func(someID)
{
    alert(someID);
    var x = document.getElementById(someID);
    alert(x);
}
```

My problem is that I would like to get the `someID` String but neither `alert(someID)` or `alert(x)` returns my result. What seems to be the problem?

`alert(someID)` --> returns `[Object HTMLImageElement]`

`alert(x)` --> returns `null`

Does functions.js even recognize the HTML elements created in the servlet?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
out.print("<img id='someID' src='somePath' onclick='func(someID)'/>");
```

to

```
out.print("<img id='someID' src='somePath' onclick='func(\"someID\")'/>");
```

Comment: Thanks it's good! and tell me. if someID value comes from a function, so instead of someID i write getValue(someVar) what should be the syntax?

Comment: this is how i wrote: i replaced /" with /' when it's inside the out.print -----> out.print("<img id='someID' src='someSrc' onclick='alertCard(/'" + func(someID) + "/')'/>\n");         is it ok?

Comment: becuase so far output is not good for me.. :( and /" doesn't go side by side " "

Comment: out.print("<img id='someID' src='someSrc' onclick='alertCard(\"" + getValue(someID) + "\")'/>\n");

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo you're the best! it's all syntax in the end of the day.. :)